# Generate random numbers in R

Tags: r, random

In R, how to generate 150 random numbers, using the numbers from 1 to 100 at least once?

```
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(123)
df <- tibble(Random_number = sample(x = 1:100,
                                    size = 150,
                                    replace = TRUE)) %>% 
  arrange(Random_number)
```

For example, the numbers 1, 2, 3, etc. never appeared.
I know that this script is not good enough to make the numbers 1 through 100 always appear at least once, as I expect, but I have no idea how to actually write the script.

Comment: You have missed a **very important point** , which is that "random" can mean many things.   This drove early iPOD users crazy because they didn't understand it.   Here, as the answers suggest, you are combining "random order of known set" with "random selection with replacement" .

Answer (score 6):

You can split your procedure into two parts: One is to ensure `1:100`, and the other is drawing additional `50` samples out of `1:100`, e.g.,

```
sample(c(1:100, sample(1:100, 50, replace = TRUE)))
```

Comment: You are right, we don't need to `sample` 1:100. So much to learn from your logic! +1!!

Comment: Sorry for the late reply.

I used the code as you suggested and got the expected results. Thank you very much.
It was simple to divide the operation of random number generation into two parts. (I lacked imagination).

Answer (score 4):

We can `sample` the numbers three times to achieve your goal. The first one `sample` 50 numbers from 1 to 100 **with** replacement. The second one randomise the sequence of 1 to 100. The third one would `sample` on the above two outputs to randomise the 150 numbers.

Note the latter two `sample` mentioned above are using the default `sample` **without** replacement.

```r
library(dplyr)

set.seed(123)

df <- tibble(Random_number = sample(c(sample(1:100, 50, replace = T), sample(1:100))))
```

The `table` result shows that the numbers from 1 to 100 are sampled at least once.

```
table(df$Random_number)

  1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17 
  1   2   1   1   1   1   1   2   1   1   2   2   3   1   1   2   1 
 18  19  20  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29  30  31  32  33  34 
  1   2   3   2   2   1   1   1   2   1   1   1   3   2   1   3   1 
 35  36  37  38  39  40  41  42  43  44  45  46  47  48  49  50  51 
  2   2   1   1   2   2   2   3   1   1   1   1   2   1   1   3   1 
 52  53  54  55  56  57  58  59  60  61  62  63  64  65  66  67  68 
  1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   2   1   1   1   2   1 
 69  70  71  72  73  74  75  76  77  78  79  80  81  82  83  84  85 
  2   1   1   1   1   3   1   2   2   1   1   1   4   3   2   2   1 
 86  87  88  89  90  91  92  93  94  95  96  97  98  99 100 
  1   1   1   2   1   1   1   2   4   1   3   1   2   1   1
```

Comment: Thank you for your excellent response.
What I lacked was flexibility.
Also, thank you for modifying the code used for the question!

Answer (score 4):

Here is a function that samples all numbers from 1 to n at least once. The final `sample` shuffles a vector that is

1. just the number `n` if `n` is greater than or equal to `size`. This is because `sample(n)` will shuffle the sequence `1:n`;
2. the sequence `1:n` plus `size - n` numbers in `1:n` if `size` is greater than `n`

```r
fun <- function(n, size, replace = TRUE) {
  x <- if(n >= size) n else c(seq.int(n), sample(n, size - n, replace = replace))
  sample(x)
}

set.seed(2023)
table(fun(100, 150))
#> 
#>   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20 
#>   1   1   2   2   2   1   1   1   2   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   2   1   2   1 
#>  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29  30  31  32  33  34  35  36  37  38  39  40 
#>   1   1   1   2   1   2   1   1   2   2   1   2   2   2   1   2   2   2   2   2 
#>  41  42  43  44  45  46  47  48  49  50  51  52  53  54  55  56  57  58  59  60 
#>   2   2   1   2   2   2   2   2   2   1   1   2   1   1   1   2   2   1   1   2 
#>  61  62  63  64  65  66  67  68  69  70  71  72  73  74  75  76  77  78  79  80 
#>   1   1   2   2   2   1   1   2   1   2   1   2   1   1   2   2   1   2   2   2 
#>  81  82  83  84  85  86  87  88  89  90  91  92  93  94  95  96  97  98  99 100 
#>   2   1   2   1   1   2   1   1   1   2   2   1   2   1   2   2   1   2   1   1
```

<sup>Created on 2023-04-08 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: I would add a `replace` argument, probably defaulting to `TRUE`. Otherwise the function will fail when size > 2n.

Comment: I'm betting that, due to the if-else, this will run slower than other answers.... off to test I go!

Comment: Thanks for the great answer.
I think it would be very useful to define it as a function since it is likely to generate random numbers many times in the simulation study.

Answer (score 3):

Well, I was wrong (see comment on Rui's answer).  Avoiding `sample` as much as possible makes things run faster.

```
Rgames> n = 1e4
Rgames> size = 1.5e4
Rgames> microbenchmark(rifelse(n,size), rtrisamp(n,size), rbisamp(n,size))
Unit: microseconds
              expr      min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval cld
  rifelse(n, size)  849.655  968.8905  982.1622  975.5885  996.2145  1089.916   100 a  
 rtrisamp(n, size) 2261.861 2365.4385 2587.5585 2374.7670 2390.5145 13360.855   100   c
  rbisamp(n, size) 1400.847 1576.1280 1684.7027 1584.5185 1592.8440 11510.640   100  b
```